# Make sure all list items based on fields exists in table efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Mode):
    foo = models.CharField(...)
    bar = models.CharField(...)
```

and I have a list contains foo and bar field values. I want to check all of items in this list, exists in the database.
For example:

```
my_list = [{'foo': 'foo_1','bar': 'bar_1'}, {'foo': 'foo_2','bar': 'bar_2'}]
```

I want to check all records exists values ​​corresponding to the list items fields in the  database. I can change my list structure.

I can do it with for loop but I want to find more efficient way. Is it possible with single query?. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check the number of instances from SQL response:

```
from django.db.models import Q

my_list = [{'foo': 'foo_1','bar': 'bar_1'}, {'foo': 'foo_2','bar': 'bar_2'}]
query = Q()
for i in my_list:
    query &= Q(foo=i['foo'], bar=i['bar'])
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(query)

assert queryset.count() == len(my_list)  # 2 == 2
```

So in case you have all values in your DB the count and len values will be same.

in case your my_list includes only proper fields you can do just:

```
for i in my_list:
    query &= Q(**i)
```

Comment: Do mention that this approach works on the assumption that `foo` and `bar` are unique together (Will fail if multiple entries exist with the same `foo` and `bar`)

Comment: It won't fall if multiple values with `foo` and `bar` exists because we use `filter`

Comment: Great, but this is not worked what i expected.  I wonder if the ` &=`  must be an  `|=` ?

Comment: If multiple entries exist with the same `foo` and `bar` the count you will get would be _wrong_ which is what I am talking about.

Comment: @kamilyrb it bases on what you need either `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: Actually I want to check all items exists in db. But when I use, `&=` count   returns 0. If i use `|=` count assigned correctly. I'm a little confused.

Comment: Ok, my fields have unique_together, so it will not any problem if i use or statement. Thanks a lot @SergeyPugach